# R: Why can one S4 object have multiple variable names?

Tags: r, r-s4, openxlsx

If I assign an ordinary object to variable `foo`, and then `foo <- bar`, then `foo` and `bar` will be two separate objects. Then, if I eventually modify `bar`, `foo` will not be modified—and vice versa.

However, this is different with S4 objects. Specifically, if I modify the object assigned to `bar`, then all assignments of this object (here: also `foo`) will be affected. Here's one example:

```
foo <- openxlsx::createWorkbook()
openxlsx::addWorksheet(foo, "Sheet 1")
writeData(foo, sheet=1, x="Hi")

openxlsx::readWorkbook(foo)
# > Hi

bar <- foo
writeData(bar, sheet=1, x="Hello")
openxlsx::readWorkbook(foo)
# > Hello
```

Why did the S/R community consider this assignment practice to be useful, when the R language works quite differently when it comes to assignments?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the package `openxlsx` but I think the behaviour you are seeing here most likely relates to this package. Do `foo` and `bar` relate to the same worksheet in memory? Similar how to variables can refer to the same file (writing to that file will then also have the same behaviour)?

Answer (score 1):

Your assertion is false --- S4 objects in general do not exhibit this behaviour:

```
> cl <- setClass("test",slots=c(x="integer"))
> z1 <- cl(x=1L)
> z2 <- z1
> identical(z1,z2)
[1] TRUE
> z2@x <- 2L
> identical(z1,z2)
[1] FALSE
```

This behaviour is specific to the class of your `foo` and `bar`, and probably is to do with the fact that they are *connections*, which can be duplicated but ultimately are probably still connected to the same file.